# ChrUbuntu on external hard drive (lsblk not found)?

Tags: installation, chromebook

I have a Chromebook (Acer C7 16gb SSD + 2Gb RAM version). I want to get Ubuntu up and running on it using ChrUbuntu. When looking at [the instructions on the blog](http://chromeos-cr48.blogspot.com/search?q=tnyga), It says to check what name my external hard drive is under by typing `lsblk | grep disk`. I just typed it in the terminal in Chrome OS & I just keep getting "Unknown command lsblk".

Anybody know how to get it to work? Please?
BTW, I am a N00b and I couldn't find anything online about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the ChrUbuntu blog it seems that [you can only boot from a USB stick or SD card](http://chromeos-cr48.blogspot.com/2012/12/so-you-want-chrubuntu-on-external-drive.html). However I have not encountered this error. Did you type `shell` after opening a new console tab (ctrl-T) in Chrome? Maybe you're not in [developer mode](http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/developer-information-for-chrome-os-devices) and running a [developer kernel (dev channel)](http://www.omgchrome.com/how-to-change-channels-on-chromebook/)? Maybe you need to upgrade to the latest version of Chrome OS.

Answer (score 0):

According to the instructions, you can't use the standard entry to the Chrome terminal. You have to be in Developer mode, and you enter the terminal by pressing Ctl+Alt+'->' where '->' is the forward arrow where F2 would be on a PC keyboard. You then log in as chronos, with no password required.